# Maven Sonarqube plugin: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server

Tags: java, docker, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm having an headache setting up the sonarqube maven plugin for a project.

So I have a sonarqube instance let's say on https://sonarqube.mycompany.software. I test many projects on this instance, it's working well since months.
I also have other projects that use the maven plugin (but use another docker image to run)

I start a new project, and of course I want to add to my automatic pipeline that checks the code with sonarqube.

Everything runs perfectly when I execute the maven plugin on my machine, with the OpenJdk-8:

```
$ mvn org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5:prepare-agent clean test package
$ mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=projectname -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.mycompany.software -Dsonar.login=youwishyouknew
[... Lots of output ...]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  16.891 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-07T18:03:00+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then I try to execute the exact same command with docker on the server (where the pipeline will run), using the `maven:3.6.3-jdk-8` image, I get this error:

```
$ docker run -v `pwd`/m2cache:/root/.m2 -v `pwd`/sonarcache:/root/.sonar/cache -v`pwd`:`pwd` -w`pwd` maven:3.6.3-jdk-8  mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=projectname -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.mycompany.software -Dsonar.login=youwishyouknew

[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------------< software.mycompany:projectname >----------------------------
[INFO] Building projectname 2.3.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) @ projectname ---
[INFO] User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
[ERROR] SonarQube server [https://sonarqube.mycompany.software] can not be reached
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.286 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-07T16:06:22Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project projectname: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Broken pipe (Write failed) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

When I Execute this, **absolutely** nothing is happening in the Sonarqube logs (nothing moves at all in any log, while when I run it on my machine I find everything I expect to find.)

Furthermore, if I try to `curl` the sonarqube server from the docker image, it works! Tried with `ping` too.

```
$ docker run -v `pwd`/m2cache:/root/.m2 -v `pwd`/sonarcache:/root/.sonar/cache -v`pwd`:`pwd` -w`pwd` maven:3.6.3-jdk-8  curl https://sonarqube.mycompany.software

<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" charset="UTF-8"/><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
[... And a lot more output ... ]
```

It responds with the sonarqube index page as I expect.

As far as I can see, there is no proxy setting in the docker maven image.

This is quite frustrating.

Has anybody any clue on what is going on here and how to fix this?

[EDIT] So I've tried many things, and one worked: using another docker image. In particular, I've tried all the available maven jdk-8 images available here: https://hub.docker.com/_/maven, and *one* actually worked, while all other failed:  `maven:3.6.3-ibmjava-8`.

It looks like a java-8 related problem, since all JDK 11 images instead do work as expected. Unfortunately the project is in Java 8 and everything breaks when upgrading the JVM :-)

I leave this here as a work-around, but still, I would like to know why it fails with other docker images and how to fix this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too with maven and gradle sonarqube analysis, i have only this issue with jdk8-u252+.
Maven 3.6.3 official image have jdk8-u262.
For me, with maven 3.5.2 it's ok (jdk-u232).

For the root cause, it could be the javax.net.ssl new features shipped in u252 : https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u251-relnotes.html